# Defining tunable new point types through macro

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot data points using symbols having a thick border of another color. 
I cqn do that by plotting twice the data points with the same symbol (e.g. a circle; `pt 7`) but with sizes differing by a given factor (here `1.5`), and of different colours, of course (here colors `1` -red- and `3` -blue-).

```
p 'data.dat' pt 7 lc 1 ps 1*1.5, '' pt 7 lc 3 ps 1
```

I am trying to achieve this through a macro. So far, I have added this line to the gnuplot initialization file (.gnuplot ot gnuplot.ini if I am not mistaken):

```
#Define points with a surrounding color
surr(a,b,c,d)=sprintf("pt %d lc %s ps %d*1.5, \"\" pt %d lc %s ps %d",a,b,d,a,c,d)
```

and in gnuplot, I would do:

```
s=surr(7,1,3,1)
p 'data.dat' @s
```

This works fine but I would like to improve it twofold:

One: being able to do sthg like

```
s=surr(7,@cblue,@cblue2,2)
```

with

```
cblue = 'rgbcolor "#0083AB"'
cblue2 = 'rgbcolor "#64A8A3"'
```

defined previously

however `@cblue` being not an integer, this does not work. On the other hand, I want to still be able to use an integer. I unfortunately does not know which format would be appropriate here.

Two: tuning the ratio between the two symbols (fixed to 1.5 in my definition). However, defining

```
surr(a,b,c,d,e)=sprintf("pt %d lc %s ps %d*%d, \"\" pt %d lc %s ps %d",a,b,d,e,a,c,d)
```

complains about the `%d*%d` and  Iahve no clue how to go around this.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have full flexibility about the parameters you give, you must use only string parameters:

```
surr(pt, lc1, lc2, ps, fac)=sprintf("pt %s lc %s ps %s*%s, \"\" pt %s lc %s ps %s", pt, lc1, ps, fac, pt, lc2, ps)
```

Now you can use whatever you want:

```
cblue = 'rgbcolor "#0083AB"'
cblue2 = 'rgbcolor "#64A8A3"'

s=surr("7",cblue,cblue2,"1", "2")
plot 'data.dat' @s
```

or

```
s = surr("7", "2", "3", "2", "4")
plot 'data.dat' @s
```

One option which would allow you to type in integers or strings would be to use the string concat operator `.`, which does an conversion from int to string (not from double to string!). Try

```
surr(pt, lc1, lc2, ps, fac) = "pt ".pt." lc ".lc1." ps ".ps.sprintf("*%f", fac).", '' pt ".pt." lc ".lc2." ps ".ps

cblue = 'rgbcolor "#0083AB"'
cblue2 = 'rgbcolor "#64A8A3"'
s=surr(7, cblue,cblue2,1, 2)

plot 'data.dat' @s
```

That does work at least on Linux, not sure if this automatic conversion also works on Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both solutions work perfectly on Mac. I did not know the string concat operator, pretty handy stuff.